# TextLayout in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

how to using Adobe TextLayout in flash devlop
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean how to enable it I guess ? Make sure you've got the latest FlexSDK installed. You may have to add textLayout.swc to your class-path as well.